# Concatenate videos from txt file while adding a watermark

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I'm trying to concatenate videos from a text file using this commmand
`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i video_folder/movies.txt -c copy video_folder/output10.mp4`

and I also want to add a watermark using this command

`ffmpeg -i video_folder/output10.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=1:600' -y video_folder/output10.mp4`

But

1. this isn't working and causing the video to only last half a second
2. I'd like to run both commands at the same time.. something like
   `ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i video_folder/movies.txt -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=1:600' video_folder/output10.mp4`
   but when I tried this I got the error
   `Streamcopy requested for output stream 0:0, which is fed from a complex filtergraph. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together.`

What's the reason that adding the watermark is breaking it, and is there a way to run both these commands at the same time?

Comment: I see nothing obviously wrong with your last command. Show the complete console output from this command, and ensure that this is the actual command you are executing.

Comment: perhaps you used `-c copy` as well like in your first example? Then it would throw that error.